Finding out all common values of a variable based on another variable
I have this table in R:
df <- data.frame(
    var1 = c("red", "red", "blue", "blue", "green", "green"),
    var2 = c("canada", "usa", "usa", "canada", "canada", "france")
)

I want to find out all values of var2 shared that are shared by all values of var1
I tried to do this the long way:
var1_categories <- unique(df$var1)
common_var2 <- lapply(var1_categories, function(cat) unique(df$var2[df$var1 == cat]))
names(common_var2) <- var1_categories

shared_var2 <- Reduce(intersect, common_var2)

result_df <- data.frame(var2 = shared_var2)

Is there something I can do in R to do this for all values of var2?
E.g.

abc is found in red, blue
def is found in red, blue, green
ghi is only found in blue
etc

I am trying something like this:
result <- df %>%
    group_by(var2) %>%
    summarize(var1_categories = list(unique(var1))) %>%
    mutate(category_count = sapply(var1_categories, length)) %>%
    mutate(var1_categories = sapply(var1_categories, paste, collapse = ", ")) %>%
    arrange(desc(category_count))


You can try
> names(which(colMeans(table(df) > 0) == 1))
[1] "canada"

where table(df) shown like below has revealed the expected output
> table(df)
       var2
var1    canada france usa
  blue       1      0   1
  green      1      1   0
  red        1      0   1


If you want a data frame that summarizes the counts of common entries, you can try
> transform(aggregate(var1 ~ var2, unique(df), list), cnt = lengths(var1))
    var2             var1 cnt
1 canada red, blue, green   3
2 france            green   1
3    usa        red, blue   2


library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarize(var1_categories = paste(unique(var1), collapse=", "), 
            category_count = n(), .by=var2) %>%
  arrange(desc(category_count))


    var2  var1_categories category_count
1 canada red, blue, green              3
2    usa        red, blue              2
3 france            green              1

